# Using webpack to bundle electron with angular

Tags: angular, performance, webpack, optimization, electron

[secure-electron-template](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template)

Used above repo to build an electron app. The author used react. We would like to use angular instead.

How to effectively use webpacks with [angular-electron](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron) like [GitHub Desktop](https://github.com/desktop/desktop)?

1. We tried by replacing angular build in /release/dist/app/renderer. It does not work.
2. We don't have good understanding of webpack-ing. We refered multiple repo. It does not work either.

`Like to achieve following  dist/app/main/ webpacked-electron-main.files dist/app/render/ webpacked-electron-render.files or dist files of angular dist/build/ electron-app.exe`